# Updating TableView Cell when Location Update is received

Tags: swift, tableview

I want to update my TableView when a location update is received and therefore update a distance label I show to the user. I have created a notification that will notify me of the update.

```
self.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "locationAvailable:", name: "LOCATION_AVAILABLE", object: nil)

func locationAvailable(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    self.currentLocation = userInfo["location"] as! CLLocation
}
```

The tableView cells are filled in the data source:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AEDTableViewCell

        let aed: AED = self.aeds[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell
        cell.streetName.text = aed.street!
        cell.owner.text = aed.owner!
        cell.distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f" + "m", calculateDistance(currentLocation: self.currentLocation, latitude: aed.latitude!, longitude: aed.longitude!))

        return cell
    }
```

I calculate the distance via a method `calculateDistance`

```
calculateDistance(currentLocation: self.currentLocation, latitude: aed.latitude!, longitude: aed.longitude!)
```

But as long as the current location is not received, there is a wrong value in my tableview.

How do I update the different cells in the tableView as soon as I receive the notification?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to just do a `tableView.reloadData()` in `locationAvailable`